# Minted not working

Tags: pdftex, minted

I'm trying to use the minted package on Windows 8. I installed python and Pygment, added C:\Python34 and C:\Python34\Scripts on my path.

When I try to compile the following latex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} %for embedding images
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{url} %for proper url entries
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\input{./a.tex}
\input{./b.tex}
…
\input{./h.tex}
```

One of the files of the input command contains this minted code:

```
\begin{minted}{csharp}

string test;

\end{minted}
```

I got the following errors, which don't make any sense to me:

```
\openout3 = `report.pyg'.
runsystem(pygmentize -l csharp -f latex -F tokenmerge -P style=default -P comma
ndprefix=PYGdefault -o "_minted-report/B3A3E546A80461696602265F0BBFCFE46439C04D
9C5223188E498C03CB02681D.pygtex" "report.pyg" )...executed.
(./_minted-report/B3A3E546A80461696602265F0BBFCFE46439C04D9C5223188E498C03CB026
81D.pygtex
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \PYGdefault
{k+kt}{string} \PYGdefault {n}{test}\PYGdefault {p}{;}
l.2 ...ring} \PYGdefault{n}{test}\PYGdefault{p}{;}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \PYGdefault {k+kt}{string} \PYGdefault
{n}{test}\PYGdefault {p}{;}
l.2 ...ring} \PYGdefault{n}{test}\PYGdefault{p}{;}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...g} \PYGdefault {n}{test}\PYGdefault
{p}{;}
l.2 ...ring} \PYGdefault{n}{test}\PYGdefault{p}{;}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: i edited my question. I really need an answer, or at least an alternative to code formatting in latex.

Comment: I get no error if I replace one of the `\input{./a.tex}` with the `minted` environment.

Comment: the `input` control sequence is not the problem. Replacing one `input` by `minted` didn't help.

Comment: As egreg asked, please turn your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228); it's the surest way to a solution.

Comment: To that end, you might find the `filecontents` environment helpful. I can't reproduce this error, either. If we can't reproduce the error, we can't help :(

Comment: Have you tried compiling using -shell-escape as an argument to latex?

Comment: This example works perfect on windows 7 and miktex. I cannot see the error above. 

Compiling with...
pdflatex --enable-write18 --extra-mem-bot=10000000 --synctex=1 %A%.tex

Answer (score 28):

I can conform this issue now. On my local machine it was impossible to reproduce this error, but on another machine I succeeded.

I have tried it like the following.

1. Installed python2.7 and pygmentize
2. Did not add path and compiled (_minted-exampleb was created as subdirectory automatically) but I failed with the above message.
3. Installed python3.4 and pygmentize
4. Added correct path to windowsenvironment and tried to compile but I also failed.
5. Deleted all temporary files and compiled once more. SUCCESSS. (pdf compiles correctly) (including _minted-%filname%)

It seems to me, that there are some old files or pathsettings which maybe don't access the same version of python and old files are still at the examplefolder.

I am working on windows 7, maybe this issue is OS independent, then you should try go remove all old python2.7 installations and remove all old temporary files of your examplefolder.

I am not sure but I think its worth to give it a try.

Comment: Deleting temporary files indeed solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, deleting the folder `_minted-maindocument` helped to solve the issue.

Comment: Cleaning up the temporary files on OSX did not resolve the issue for me.

Comment: For me this also didn't solve the issue... I'm working on WIndows 10 with MikTex and TexMaker: My question: [here](tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339154/latex-minted-not-working-with-miktex-texmaker-under-windows-10)

Comment: Deleting the `minted-...` folder fixed the issue for me too!

Answer (score 3):

I also got error messages when including minted. I tried many different things, but what finally solved my problem was including minted (`\usepackage{minted}`) as first package.

Comment: Hm, it did solve my issue as well