# Color in a multirow cell with extra vertical space

Tags: colortbl

I am using `colortbl` and `booktabs` to make the following table with `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}

\tcbset{
enhanced,
title=Factorización,                
colbacktitle=black,                 
coltitle=white,                     
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\Large, 
attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-8pt},
boxed title style={
enhanced,
boxrule=0.4mm,
frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame,black] (frame.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=7pt]frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([yshift=7pt]frame.south east) -- ([xshift=-7pt]frame.south east);},
interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior,black!75] (interior.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]interior.north west) -- ([xshift=7pt]interior.north west) -- (interior.north east) -- ([yshift=7pt]interior.south east) -- ([xshift=-7pt]interior.south east);} },
leftrule=0mm,
toprule=0mm,
colframe=black,                     
colback=white,                      
coltext=black,                      
arc=0pt,
boxsep=0mm,
left=0mm,
right=0mm,
bottom=0mm,
width=12cm,
}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{tabular}{
>{\columncolor{gray!50}}P{5cm}|
P{7cm}
}
\addlinespace[1mm]
 & $a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}=(a+b)^{2}$ \\ 
\multirow{2}{*}[12pt]{Trinomio cuadrado perfecto} & $a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}=(a-b)^{2}$ \\
\hline
Diferencia de cuadrados & $a^{2}-b^{2}=(a+b)(a-b)$ \\
\hline 
Suma de cubos & $a^{3}+b^{3}=(a+b)(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})$ \\
\hline  
Diferencia de cubos & $a^{3}-b^{3}=(a-b)(a^{2}+ab+b^{2})$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe I am very picky but you can see that the exponents in the second, third and fourth row are touching the `\hline` so in order to solve this I add extra vertical space using `\addlinespace` in each row but unfortunately I get this

[image]

with this code

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{tabular}{
>{\columncolor{gray!50}}P{5cm}|
M{7cm}
}
\addlinespace[1mm]
 & $a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}=(a+b)^{2}$ \\ 
\multirow{2}{*}[12pt]{Trinomio cuadrado perfecto} & $a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}=(a-b)^{2}$ \\
\hline
\addlinespace[0.8mm]
Diferencia de cuadrados & $a^{2}-b^{2}=(a+b)(a-b)$ \\
\hline 
\addlinespace[0.8mm]
Suma de cubos & $a^{3}+b^{3}=(a+b)(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})$ \\
\hline  
\addlinespace[0.8mm]
Diferencia de cubos & $a^{3}-b^{3}=(a-b)(a^{2}+ab+b^{2})$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

How can I solve this vertical and color issue.

Comment: Problematic is not `multirow` but use of `\addlinespace` from `booktabs`. For possible solution see my answer below.

Comment: That's the way I want the table the problem now is that I get this error `Package minted Error: You must have 'pygmentize' installed to use this package. \begin{document}` How can I solve this? I've seen all the similars answers to my problem but nothing works

Comment: Ah, `minted` .. i have similar problem width it, unfortunately I didn't solve the problem myself ... I need to ask my system administrator, how he managed this problem. Since I'm temporary abroad, I can't ask him for help. I'm sure, that in SE is somewhere answer how to install it. If you cannot find, just ask new question about it.

Comment: Ok I'll ask a question about it.  is there a way to get what a I want without using minted???

Comment: Minted is based/use python, and here is problem. Yes, it is posible, I hope that I will upgrade my answer with (less elegant) solutuion. Anyway, for use all capability of `tcolorbox`, `mdframed`, coloring of listings is good idea to install python and activate minted is worth of effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you looking for something like this:

[image]

For above image I omit package `booktabs`, for more space above equations I use a trick `$\vskip-1ex$` but main point is use `tabularx` capability of `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[dvipsname,table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{array,tabularx}
    \usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{minted}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{enhanced,
        colbacktitle=black, coltitle=white,
        fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\Large,
        attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-4pt},
boxed title style={enhanced,
                   boxrule=0.4mm,
                   frame code = {\path[tcb fill frame,black] 
                (frame.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]frame.north west) -- 
                ([xshift=7pt]frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- 
                ([yshift=7pt]frame.south east) -- ([xshift=-7pt]frame.south east);},
interior code ={\path[tcb fill interior,black!75] 
                (interior.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]interior.north west) -- ([xshift=7pt]interior.north west) -- (interior.north east) -- ([yshift=7pt]interior.south east) -- ([xshift=-7pt]interior.south east);}
                    },
        leftrule=0mm,toprule=0mm,
        colframe=black,colback=white,coltext=black,
        arc=0pt,
        boxsep=0mm,
        left=0mm,right=0mm,bottom=0mm,
        width=12cm,
tabularx={>{\columncolor{gray!30}}X | >{$}P{66mm}<{$}},
        }
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Factorización]\sffamily
Trinomio cuadrado perfecto  &   $\vskip -1ex$
                                a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}=(a+b)^{2} \newline
                                a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}=(a-b)^{2}           \\
    \hline
Diferencia de cuadrados     &   a^{2}-b^{2}=(a+b)(a-b)              \\
    \hline
Suma de cubos               &   a^{3}+b^{3}=(a+b)(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})   \\
    \hline
Diferencia de cubos         &   a^{3}-b^{3}=(a-b)(a^{2}+ab+b^{2}) 
%    \hline
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{document}
```

**Upgrade:**
Less elegant possible solution, which not required installed python and minted package:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\tcbset{enhanced,
       top=0pt,
       boxrule=0.4mm,
%
colbacktitle=black,coltitle=white,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\Large,
attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-8pt},
boxed title style = {enhanced,
                     frame code={\path[tcb fill frame,black]
                        (frame.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=7pt]frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([yshift=7pt]frame.south east) -- ([xshift=-7pt]frame.south east);},
                    interior code={\path[tcb fill interior,black!75]
                        (interior.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]interior.north west) -- ([xshift=7pt]interior.north west) -- (interior.north east) -- ([yshift=7pt]interior.south east) -- ([xshift=-7pt]interior.south east);} },
leftrule=0.4mm,
 toprule=0.4mm,
colframe=black,colback=white,coltext=black,
arc=0pt,
boxsep=0mm,
left=0mm,right=0mm,bottom=0mm,width=12cm,
}

    \usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand\rspace{\rule[-5pt]{0pt}{15pt}}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Factorización]\sffamily
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{gray!50}}P{5cm}|>{$}P{6.1cm}<{$}}
Trinomio cuadrado perfecto  &   $\vskip-0.5ex$ 
                                a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}=(a+b)^{2}   \newline
                                a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}=(a-b)^{2}           \\
\hline
Diferencia de cuadrados     &   a^{2}-b^{2}=(a+b)(a-b)              \rspace\\
\hline
Suma de cubos               &   a^{3}+b^{3}=(a+b)(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})   \rspace\\
\hline
Diferencia de cubos         &   a^{3}-b^{3}=(a-b)(a^{2}+ab+b^{2})   \rspace\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}
    \end{document}
```

It gives the same result as before. However it require more manual adjusting.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko I will use the second one right now but I like to use the first code you gave It will be OK if I ask about this problem with minted? I've been looking similar answers and no one seems to work

Comment: Recently I didn't search on SE about python, minted ... on SE but I have in memory, that I found here instruction, how to install this. On the end it was simple (words of system administrator, who did this for me).

Comment: About minted see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237075/minted-not-working. In answer are instruction, what too do, that it will works.